# Inversion with of?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Could the prepositional verb "of" be used with inversion?

As so:

" **Of the apple there was nothing left**, for the worm had found it's way inside and it could only be thrown away."

Is the emboldened part grammatical with regard to fronting prepositions?

Comment: Many people translate the first line of Virgil's *Aeneid* as "Of arms and the man I sing." (http://www.todayinliterature.com/stories.asp?Event_Date=6/11/1184)

Comment: Yes, you could do this.